# Is it possible to determine which database objects were created with quoted identifiers in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, quoted-identifier

I have a schema in which a small number of the thousands of stored procedures have been created with quoted identifiers. I need to fix them. The only way I currently have of identifying them is by opening them up in SQLDeveloper, one at a time, and checking to see if the `CREATE OR REPLACE...` bit at the top has quotes around the procedure name. Does anyone have any cunning method of identifying these troublesome objects more easily? Have I overlooked some Oracle system view with a `this_uses_quoted_identifiers` flag, perhaps? Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways:

```
select * from all_source where type = 'PROCEDURE' and line = 1 and text like '%"%'
```

and

```
select * from all_procedures where procedure_name != upper(procedure_name)
```

However, none of them is 100% correct and complete. The first one looks for **any** double quote in the first line. The second one would only find procedures with lower caps in their name which would mean that double quotes have been used.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you quote an identifier, but all the letters are in capital form, it is just equivalent to non quoted identifier.
So you can select from ALL_OBJECTS to see which object names have names with non capital letters.

Comment: That's not entirely true, you would have to use double quotes if you wanted the first letter of the object name to be a number for instance.